# Probability you get $12$ before two consecutive $7$s

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains, dice

Here is a question from a probability textbook I am working through:

> Two players bet on roll(s) of the total of two standard six-face dice. Player $A$ bets that a sum of $12$ will occur first. Player $B$ bets that two consecutive $7$'s will occur first. The players keep rolling the dice and record the sums until one player wins. What is the probability that $A$ will win?

I got the two equations$$p_0 = {1\over{36}} + {1\over6}p_1 + {{29}\over{36}}p_0, \quad p_1 = {1\over{36}} + {{29}\over{36}}p_0.$$Solving for $p_0$, I ended up with $p_0 = {5\over{13}}$. However, the answer in my book is $p_0 = {7\over{13}}$. Which is correct?

Comment: Not sure what the $p_i$ are.  I think that $p_0$ is the probability that $A$ eventually wins, given that no relevant score has happened already, and that $p_1$ is the probability that $A$ eventually wins given that one $7$ has been recorded.  If so, I agree with your equations but note that they resolve to $p_0=\frac 7{13}, \,p_1=\frac 6{13}$.  (I am not sure why they sum to $1$, doubt it means anything).

Comment: @lulu I would word it like this: $p_0$ is the probability that $A$ eventually wins given that there was not a $7$ immediately beforehand (which includes the case where there was no previous score), and $p_1$ is the probability that $A$ eventually wins given that there was a $7$ immediately beforehand.

Comment: If we did the same thing for B, we will get $p_0 = \frac{6}{13}$ and $p_1 = \frac{7}{13}$. This shows that P(B wins|first toss = 7) = P(A wins).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be modelled as an absorbing Markov chain with four states: "normal", "one $7$ appeared", "A won" and "B won". The transition matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
29/36&29/36&0&0\\
1/6&0&0&0\\
1/36&1/36&1&0\\
0&1/6&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Diagonalising to take the limit of powers of this matrix, then right-multiplying by the initial state of $(1,0,0,0)^T$, yields $(0,0,7/13,6/13)^T$ – i.e. A wins with probability $\frac7{13}$ as per the provided answer.