# equivalent states in a markov chain

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Two players bet on the sum of two standard six-face dice. Player A bets that the sum of 12 will occur first. Player B bets that two consecutive sum of 7s will occur first. What is the probability that A will win? Here is the same question [Probability you get $12$ before two consecutive $7$s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494380/probability-you-get-12-before-two-consecutive-7s), but I do not understand the reasoning presented.

The solution I am looking at draws only four states:

1. the starting state
2. the state where the sum is 7
3. the state where we get two consecutive 7-7
4. the state where the sum is 12

The solution also claims that "you can use all combinations of the outcomes of the one roll and two consecutive rolls as states to construct a transition matrix and you will get the same final result"

It seems to be suggesting that to define a state we need to look at both the current sum and two consecutive sums.

1). What sequences of random variables should we be looking at to define the state here?
2). Why do we not care about states like the sum of the current rolls is 6?

Comment: Regarding (2):  Does either player *care* if the previous roll summed to 6?

Comment: Intuitively it does not really matter. What is the mathematical term or statement to make this idea precise though @XanderHenderson

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your comment.  You *could* model this system by looking at every possible outcome of two consecutive dice rolls (there would be a total of $11\cdot 10 = 110$ such states).  But only some of those states actually matter.  The "game" here is to figure out which states matter, and only model those.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase. What is the mathematical proof that the rest of the states do not matter? Or to begin with how do you define "matter" mathematically? @XanderHenderson

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of "proof" you are looking for.  This is a modeling problem.  In trying to take this "real world" problem and model it with mathematics, the goal is to abstract away the things which are not mathematically relevant.  I mean, you could define all $110$ states (or, even worse, you could model every possible combination of dice rolls over two rolls of two dice, for a total of $6^4$ possible states.  The point of the exercise is to recognize that many of those states are equivalent---from the point of view of progressing the game, a $3$ and a $10$ are the same.

Comment: @Adam When you say "the rest of the states do not matter", I think you mean that they correspond to identical distributions of states for the next step in the chain. Given that the last roll summed to $X \ne 7$ you can determine the probabilities of the next state in the chain. The actual value of $X$ is not required to determine the distribution of the next step. It makes sense then to consider all of these as the same state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most pedantically accurate probability space for modelling the process you describe would have a sample space $\ \Omega\ $ of elementary outcomes represented by finite sequences, $\ \big(\omega_{11}, \omega_{21}\big),$$\, \big(\omega_{11}, \omega_{21}\big),$$\,\dots,$$\,\big(\omega_{1n},\omega_{2n}\big)\ $, of pairs of numbers with the following properties

- $\ \omega_{1t},\omega_{2t}\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\ $.
- Either $\ \omega_{1n}+\omega_{2n}=12\ $ or $\ \omega_{1n}+\omega_{2n}=7\ $ and $\ \omega_{1\,n-1}+d_{2\,n-1}=7\ $.
- For any $\ t<n\ $$\ \omega_{1t}+\omega_{2t}\ne12\ $ , and either $\ \omega_{1t}+\omega_{2t}\ne7\ $ or $\ \omega_{1\,t-1}+\omega_{2\,t-1}\ne7\ $.

Since the sample space is countable, you can take the $\ \sigma$-algebra of events to be its power set, $\ 2^\Omega\ $, and
$$
\mathbb{P}(E)=\sum_{\omega\in E}36^{-|w|}\ . 
$$
for any $\ E\subseteq\Omega\ $, where $\ |w|\ $ is the number of terms in the sequence $\ \omega\ $. Let
$$
\Omega_n=\{\,\omega\in\Omega\,|\,|\omega|=n\,\}\ .
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\big(\Omega_n\big)&=\sum_{\omega\in \Omega_n}36^{-|w|}\\
&=\frac{\big|\,\Omega_n\,\big|}{36^n}\\
\Omega_i\cap\Omega_j&=\varnothing\ \text{ for }\ i\ne j,\ \text{ and}\\
\Omega&=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\Omega_n\ ,
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\Omega)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}\big(\Omega_n\big)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\big|\,\Omega_n\,\big|}{36^n}\ .
\end{align}
For  $\ \big(\Omega, 2^\Omega, \mathbb{P}\big)\ $ to satisfy the definition of a  probability space, this sum has to be equal to $\ 1\ $, which is not immediately obvious.  Here's one way showing that it is, which I think nicely illustrates how the states of the Markov chain you're looking for arise naturally from the structure of this probability space, and can hence be defined as a stochastic process on it.

Let $\ V_n=\big(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2\big)^n\ $,
\begin{align}
A_n&=\big\{\,v\in V_n\,\big|\,v\subsetneq\omega\ \text{ for some }\ \omega\in\Omega,\,v_{1n}+v_{2n}\ne7\,\big\}\ ,\\
B_n&=\big\{\,v\in V_n\,\big|\,v\subsetneq\omega\ \text{ for some }\ \omega\in\Omega,\,v_{1n}+v_{2n}=7\,\big\}
 ,\\
C_n&=\big\{\,v\in V_n\,\big|\,\omega\subseteq   v\ \text{ for some }\ \omega\in\Omega\ \text{ with }\ \omega_{1\,|\omega|}+\omega_{2\,|\omega|}=12\,\big\}
 ,\\
D_n&=\big\{\,v\in V_n\,\big|\,\omega\subseteq   v\ \text{ for some }\ \omega\in\Omega\ \text{ with }\ \omega_{1\,|\omega|}+\omega_{2\,|\omega|}=7\,\big\}\ ,\\
a_n&=\big|A_n\big|\ ,\\
b_n&=\big|B_n\big|
 ,\\
c_n&=\big|C_n\big|\ ,\\
d_n&=\big|D_n\big|\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ u\subseteq w\ $ means that the finite sequence $\ u\ $ is an initial segment of the finite sequence $\ w\ $ (which could possibly be the whole of $\ w\ $), and $\ u\subsetneq w\ $ means it is an initial segment which is *strictly shorter* than $\ w\ $.  Note that $\ A_n\cup B_n\cup C_n\cup D_n=V_n\ $ and $\ C_n\cup D_n=\bigcup_\limits{j=1}^n\Omega_j\times V_{n-j}\ $, and so
\begin{align}
\left|\,\bigcup_\limits{j=1}^n\Omega_j\times V_{n-j}\ \right|&=\sum_{j=1}^n36^{n-j}\big|\Omega_j\big|\\
&=\big|\,C_n\cup D_n\,\big|\\
&=c_n+d_n\ .
\end{align}
It's not difficult to show that $\ a_n,b_n, c_n\ $ and $\ d_n\ $ satisfy the recursions
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&=29\big(a_n+b_n\big)\\
b_{n+1}&=6a_n\\
c_{n+1}&=a_n+b_n+36c_n\\
d_{n+1}&=6b_n+36d_n
\end{align}
and initial conditions. $\ a_1=29$,$\,b_1=6$,$\,c_1=1$, and $\ d_1=0\ $.  We can write these equations in matrix form as
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{a_{n+1}\\b_{n+1}\\c_{n+1}\\d_{n+1}}&=\pmatrix{29&29&0&0\\
     6&0&0&0\\
     1&1&36&0\\                          0&6&0&36}\pmatrix{a_n\\b_n\\c_n\\d_n}\\
\pmatrix{a_1\\b_1\\c_1\\d_1}&=\pmatrix{29&29&0&0\\
     6&0&0&0\\
     1&1&36&0\\                          0&6&0&36}\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\0}\ .
\end{align}
Dividing these equations through by $\ 36^{n+1}\ $  and $\ 36\ $, respectively, and setting $\ \pi_n=\pmatrix{\frac{a_n}{36^n}&\frac{b_n}{36^n}&\frac{c_n}{36^n}&\frac{d_n}{36^n}}^\top\ $ , we get
\begin{align}
\pi_{n+1}&=\pmatrix{\frac{29}{36}&\frac{29}{36}&0&0\\
 \frac{1}{6} &0&0&0\\
\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&1&0\\
   0&\frac{1}{6}&0&1}\pi_n\\
&=\pmatrix{\frac{29}{36}&\frac{29}{36}&0&0\\
 \frac{1}{6} &0&0&0\\
\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&1&0\\
   0&\frac{1}{6}&0&1}^n\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\0}\ .
\end{align}
Now observe that the $4\times4$ matrix $\ P=\pmatrix{\frac{29}{36}&\frac{29}{36}&0&0\\
 \frac{1}{6} &0&0&0\\
\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&1&0\\
   0&\frac{1}{6}&0&1}\ $ appearing in the right side of these equations is the transition matrix of the Markov chain described in [the answer you cited](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494380/probability-you-get-12-before-two-consecutive-7s#4495001).  This Markov chain has two transient states, $\ 1\ $ and $\ 2\ $, and two absorbing states, $\ 3\ $ and $\ 4\ $.  It follows that $\ \pi_n\ $ must converge to a stationary distribution of the chain, $\ \pmatrix{0&0&f&g}^\top\ $, in which $\ f+g=1\ \ \big($as it happens, $\ f=\frac{7}{13}\ $ and $\ g=\frac{6}{13}\ \big)$. Thus
\begin{align}
1&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\big(\pi_{n3}+\pi_{n4}\big)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{c_n}{36^n}+\frac{d_n}{36^n}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\big|\,\Omega_j\,\big|}{36^j}\\
&=\mathbb{P}(\Omega)\ .
\end{align}

If we now define a stochastic process $\ X:\mathbb{N}\times\Omega\rightarrow\{1,2,3,4\}\ $ by
$$
X_n(\omega)=\cases{1&if $\ n<|\omega|\ \text{ and }\ \omega_{1n}+\omega_{2n}\ne7$\\
2&if $\ n<|\omega|\ \text{ and }\ \omega_{1n}+\omega_{2n}=7$\\
3&if $\ n\ge |\omega|\ \text{ and }\ \omega_{1\,|\omega|}+\omega_{2\,|\omega|}=12$\\
4&if $\ n\ge |\omega|\ \text{ and }\ \omega_{1\,|\omega|}+\omega_{2\,|\omega|}=7\ $}
$$
I don't think it's hard to obtain the following identities (though I must admit that I haven't actually gone through the derivations in detail):
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\big(X_{n+1}=i\,\big|\,X_n=j,&X_{n-1}=j_{n-1},\dots,X_1=j_1\,\big)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\big(X_{n+1}=i\,\big|\,X_n=j\big)\\
&=P_{ij}\ ,
\end{align}
which gives you the Markov chain you're looking for, with transition matrix $\ P\ $.

Answer (score 1):

It might start to imagine how a game might be played.  Imagine that the rolls occur:

\begin{align}
1+5&=6 && \text{neither player cares} \\
2+5&=7 && \text{player B wins if the next roll is a $7$} \\
1+1&=2 && \text{player B doesn't end; the game resets} \\
5+1&=6 && \text{neither player cares} \\
5+6&=11 && \text{neither player cares} \\
6+6&=12 && \text{player A wins}
\end{align}

From this, it seems that there are only four states which actually matter:

1. Player B wins if the next roll is a $7$ (which means that the last roll was also a $7$).
2. Player B has won (the previous two rolls were $7$s).
3. Player A has won (the previous roll was a $12$).
4. Anything else (the previous roll was neither a $7$ nor a $12$).

Note that I am not thinking of the dice rolls as the states, but rather the thing which drives the transitions between states.  This is kind of a distinction without a difference, but I think that it helps to understand what is going on.

Transition probabilities work as follows:

- If the system is in state 1, there are three possible outcomes:  either a $7$ is rolled and the system transitions to state 2 and the game ends (this happens with probability $1/6$); a $12$ is rolled and the game ends (this happens with probability $5/6$); or anything else is rolled and the system transitions to state 4 (this happens with probability $29/36$).
- If the system is in state 2, the game is over.  It is impossible for the system to transition away from this state; that is, the system remains in state 2 with probability 1.
- If the system is in state 3, the game is over.  It is impossible for the system to transition away from this state; that is, the system remains in state 3 with probability 1.
- If the system is in state 4, then it transitions to state 1 with probability $1/6$ (if a $7$ is rolled); it transitions to state 3 with probability $1/36$ (if a $12$ is rolled); or it remains in state 4 with probability $29/36$ (if anything else is rolled).

Thus the transition matrix is given by
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{29}{36} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{29}{36}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and well-written answer. If I understand correctly, a state in a Markov chain is defined through a random variable. Would you mind elaborating a little bit on what random variable we are using to define the states here?

Comment: @Adam I am not sure what you mean---but I am not an expert in probability theory, and it has been 20 years since I've thought hard about Markov chains.  There is an underlying sequence of random variables, but I could tell you what that sequence is.

Comment: To me, the point of Markov chains was always that you can "abstract away" that underlying sequence.